# How to run script from different startpoint depending on inputted value?

Tags: python, oop

So I am creating an experiment in python in which there are several tasks. I want to create a function which can start the experiment from a different start point if the experiment is quit mid-way through e.g., after 2 tasks I want it to start from the third.

When the run function (for the entire experiment) is called, you can pass 'restart=True' which then calls a restart function:

```
    def __init__(self, portname, restart=False):
        self.__port_name = portname
        self.__path = '/Users/emilia/Documents/Dementia task piloting/Lumo'
        self.__restart = restart

    def __restart(self):
        if self.__restart:
            restart_point = {'Task to restart from': ''}
            dlg = gui.DlgFromDict(dictionary=restart_point, sortKeys=False, title='Where do you want to restart from?')
            if not dlg.OK:
                print("User pressed 'Cancel'!")
                core.quit()
            return restart_point['Task to restart from']
        else:
            return None

    def run(self):
        start_point = self.__restart()
        if start_point:  # TODO: how to run from start point
            pass
        else: # Run tasks
            auditory_exp = self.__auditory_staircase(5)
            object_recognition_exp = self.__object_recognition()
            self.__resting_state()
            simple_motor_exp = self.__simple_motor_task()
            naturalistic_motor_exp = self.__naturalistic_motor_task()
            self.__end_all_experiment()
```

In the final run function which calls all of the tasks (the functions of which aren't shown here), how do I get it to skip to the task name inputted into the dialogue box should restart=True? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As all your tasks are called subsequently, a simple way would be to put your tasks in a list and iterate over it:

```
import random

class Experiment:
    def auditory_staircase(self, i: int):
        print(f"Run: Auditory Staircase (i: {i})")

    def object_recognition(self):
        print(f"Run: Object Recognition")

    def resting_state(self):
        print(f"Run: Resting State")

    def load(self, taskname: str):
        # If you need to load previous results
        print(f"Load: {taskname}")

    def restart(self):
        """ Selects a random start point """
        return random.choice([None, "Auditory Staircase", "Object Recognition", "Resting State"])

    def run(self): 
        # List of the tasks with function, arguments and keyword-arguments
        tasks = [
            ("Auditory Staircase", self.auditory_staircase, [5], {}),
            ("Object Recognition", self.object_recognition, [], {}),
            ("Resting State", self.resting_state, [], {}),
        ]

        start_from = self.restart()
        print(f"restart() returned: {start_from}")
        if start_from == None:
            start_from = tasks[0][0]

        # Iterate over the tasks, and either load previous result or start them
        started = False
        for taskname, fn, args, kwargs in tasks:
            if taskname == start_from:
                started = True

            if started:
                fn(*args, **kwargs)
            else:
                self.load(taskname)


# Run 10 experiments
e = Experiment()
for i in range(10):
    print(f"---- Run {i} ----")
    e.run()
    print("")
```

This code runs 10 different experiments, each with a random start_point. The output looks like this:

```
---- Run 0 ----
restart() returned: Auditory Staircase
Run: Auditory Staircase (i: 5)
Run: Object Recognition
Run: Resting State

---- Run 1 ----
restart() returned: Resting State
Load: Auditory Staircase
Load: Object Recognition
Run: Resting State

---- Run 2 ----
restart() returned: None
Run: Auditory Staircase (i: 5)
Run: Object Recognition
Run: Resting State

...
```

I included some code to load the results from the previous run. If you don't need that, you can skip that of course.

Comment: Thanks! How do I iterate over the list of tasks and have a different start point in the loop depending on what task name was inputted into the restart function? Currently I have it such that if the 'start_point' != taskname, it will pass and keep looping through the list until start_point == taskname and then selecting the respective fn and running it? Is this the best way of doing it?

Comment: In the code snippet that I shared above, one can change the variable `start_from` to start from a different point. Does that help?

Comment: Yes. The function 'restart' returns a 'start_from' depending on the user input as to which function they want to start from. I've modified it such if restart is false (the default value when first time running the script), it just calls the functions in order but if restart is true, the function restart is called which asks for user input to get the function which the user wants to start from. How do I then skip to the function provided and continue looping FROM that different start point?

Comment: I have the following:
```
start_from = 'Introduction'
for taskname, fn, args, kwargs in tasks:
     if not self.__restart:
          fn(*args, **kwargs)
     else:
           start_from = self.__restart()
            if start_from != taskname:
                   pass
            else:
                   fn(*args, **kwargs)
```
Is this correct?

Comment: If I read your code correct, it will only execute one task, namely the task defined by `start_from`.

Look at my example of the for-iteration, I added a boolean variable `started` that is False at the beginning, but will switch to True as soon as the iteration reaches the task where it should start.

Comment: If you cannot alter your __restart function, you could add this bit into the run function: ```if start_from == None:    start_from = tasks[0][0]``` to set `start_from` to the first task from the list. You would make sure that your task list is not empty of course.

Comment: I edited my answer, by adding a `restart()` method, that selects a random start_point. I hope this makes the logic in the for-iteration of the `run()` method more clear.